# Regex - Until the first occurrence of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried creating the regex I need, but even after half an hour I still didn't succeed.

The regex should go like this:
`hey` string followed by ANY characters (new lines as well), that finishes with the first occourence of `</div>` string.

I've tried doing that but when I allow anything after the `hey` string, it becomes too greedy and returns one match that contains `hey` and anything after that, instead of giving me multiple matches that finishes with a `</div>`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `"" string`? Is that supposed to be 2 double quotes?

Comment: I had a bad quating, sorry. have a look at the fix - it should be a </div> string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to create the desired regex:

hey((\s)|(.))*?

my attitude was a bit wrong, since if I want to find the first occurrence of something i should simply write it, but I made it thanks to craig1231 that let me know how to do it lazily.

Answer (score 5):

Would this work? Give this a try.

.*? Means a non greedy any char any length

```
hey.*?'
```

Comment: thanks, good to know this one. anyway, I still need to find the first occourence of </div> string.

Answer (score 1):

craig1231 is right, the `?` after the `*` makes the regex non-greedy. I'm not sure what you meant by:

> first occourence of "" string

If that's supposed to be 2 double quotes, then try something like this in C#:

```
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, "hey.*?\"\"", RegexOptions.Singleline)) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

The `RegexOptions.Singleline` is necessary because you also want to capture newlines, etc.

Comment: I had a bad quating, look at the fix - its a </div> string